# CSS background not showing on browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My css background image shows on dreamweaver but not in my google chrome browser for some reason it just shows a white background can anyone understand why? This is my code:

about.php file

```
<?php
include 'secure/db_connect.php';
include 'secure/functions.php';
sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a php session.
if(login_check($mysqli) == true) { ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>The Referee Perception Exam</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="css/aboutstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>paragraph here</p> 
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Contact:</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Social:</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 3</h3>        

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
<?php } else {
   header( 'Location: http://localhost/project/index.php' ) ;
}

;?>
```

aboutstyle.css file

```
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
      background-image: url("../img/pitch.jpeg");
    background-color: #cccccc;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: Do you see any 404s in console?

Comment: @rax no it shows no 404s, could it be to do with that the image is saved on my apache server and there may be forbidden access?

Comment: @bcfcmatt92 if you were to be forbidden on an image you would then get 403 on the console.

Comment: If you get a white background, then that must means your css file is not included. because otherwise you would get a grey one. Two things to test. In your browser go to that `about.php` page, then remove the `above.php` from your url and that part only. Paste `css/aboutstyle.css` at the end, do you get the css ? Then remove the `aboutstyle.css` part only and do add `../img/pitch.jpeg` do you get the background image ?

Answer (score 1):

Guessing from the file structure I can see you might need to alter

```
background-image: url("../img/pitch.jpeg");
```

maybe to

```
background-image: url("../../img/pitch.jpeg");
```

or similar to correctly reach the image file from your stylesheet. But I can't be sure without seeing the structure. 404 errors in your browser should point you in the right direction.